# Cant cancel all local notifications in iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

When i have multiple local notifications and i try to cancel them with :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

I keep getting them anyway . i have read there is some bug about it in `Xcode 7`, and i couldn't find solution for this .

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9226

How can we launch if we cant cancel notifications ?

Comment: Wait for the bug to be fixed. That's the solution I guess :/

Comment: What if you loop all available notifications and cancel them 1 by 1?

Comment: Yes you can do it using loop

Comment: Well the thing is that it shows that there are no notifications in the list, but it DOES fires them to your home screen anyway...